# Creating text files from column in data frame in R without for loop

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to create individual text files from columns in a data-frame using dplyr and the and the map function from the purrr package so that I do not have to create a for loop and can use the the existing column names as the file name for the new txt file.

Here is the dataframe:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

Then I created this function:

```
textfilecreate <- function(filename){
    filename1 <- noquote(names(filename))
    colunmname <- select(filename, filename1)
    myfile <- paste0( "_", colunmname, ".txt")
    write.table(colunmname, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, 
                col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
}
```

Then I called the map function:

```
map(data_link, textfilecreate)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in noquote(names(filename)) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I know that I am missing something but I cannot quite pinpoint what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will have same error if you try `noquote(names(df$n))` because `map` will apply the funtion to each column which have no `names`

Answer (score 2):

One of the difficulties here is that `map` loops through each column one at a time, so you end up working on a vector of values instead of data.frame.  This leads to the problems you were having with `noquote`.

However, you don't need to do any `select`-ing here, as `map` will loop through and return each column.  The remaining issue is how to get the names for the file names.

One alternative is to loop through the dataset and the column names simultaneously, creating the file name with the names and using each column as the file to save.  I use `walk2` instead of `map2` to loop through two lists simultaneously as it doesn't create a new list.

Two argument function:

```
textfilecreate = function(filename, name){
        myfile = paste0( "_", name, ".txt")
        write.table(filename, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, 
                    col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
}
```

Now loop through the dataset and the column names via `walk2`.  The first list is used as the first argument and the second list as the second argument by default.

```
walk2(df, names(df), textfilecreate)
```

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(names(df), function(colname) write.table(df[,colname],file=paste0(colname,'.txt')))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.